# Ошибка устоновки: This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources на Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux

Хочу банально установить хром.

Иду в ubuntu software center. 
Ввожу пароль рута. 
При установке пишет следующее:

> This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources

использовал такой хак:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

но сейчас он говорит, что нет интернета

`apt-get` отлично поставил skype. Про отсутствие инета сказал ubuntu центр. 
и скайп тоже инет не видит.

В настройках указал прокси.

Comment: *но сейчас он говорит что нет интернета* — процитируйте, пожалуйста, что именно пишет программа *apt-get*.

Comment: т.е. *apt-get* отлично скачивает пакеты из интернета, а *skype* не может соединиться? *ping*-и во внешний мир ходят? в браузере какие-нибудь сайты «открываются»?

Answer (score 1):

Если жалуется на интернет а пакет нужен срочно то скачаете с любой другой машины у которой доступ в интернет есть .deb пакет с нужной программой и в консоли вводите команду `sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb` если пакет лежит в корне, тобишь в папке /home/user/. Если сам пакет лежит в другой дериктории то после dpkg -i укажите точную директорию где лежит пакет.